# Meteor with iron router and login buttons

Tags: javascript, button, authentication, meteor, iron-router

I am making a project with Meteor (Meteor.com) where I would like to use iron-router for the page routing, as well as the built-in accounts-ui package for login functionality.

Before using iron-router, my `{{loginButtons}}` worked fine, but after adding iron-router, they no longer show up and the entire page will not load. If I take `{{loginButtons}}` out, it works fine.

Any idea of what is going on, or a solution?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you've upgraded (or Meteorite upgraded) the project's Meteor version to the latest (0.8.1). In the new version you need to use `{{> loginButtons}}`. See [the wiki](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Using-Blaze#upgrading-to-blaze) for more migration instructions.

Comment: perf. thanks. now I just have to configure the login services which I'm guessing is also new.